# Long fingers tip to tip

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Anne says, ‘It is all about me.’ He bows. ‘When finally you have out
>   of More what troubles his singular conscience, you will find that what
>   is at the root of it is that he will not bend his knee to my
>   queenship.’ She is small and white and angry. **Long fingers tip to tip**,
>   bending each other back; eyes bright.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Does the **bold phrase** mean something like the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite certain that you have not identified the correct gesture, because you have missed the next phrase, "bending each other back." Instead I think the passage is probably describing a gesture sometimes called "steepling". This is a gesture which might be made by someone who is angry (but thinking calmly), so with the context I think it's the best interpretation. But the whole quote is not that clear so it could be something else.

[An example of someone making the steepling gesture http://www.szubotinpeter.hu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image_4236377.jpg](http://www.szubotinpeter.hu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image_4236377.jpg)